# How to convert from byte data for serial port

Tags: javascript, serial-port

How can I convert a hex string like this `\x02\x00\x01\x04\x20\x27`

into an array like this: `[0x02,0x00,0x01,0x04,0x20,0x27]`

Maybe it is because I don't know the appropriate names for this type of data, but I cannot find the answer.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly the string is, how to read it. What is its length? 6 or 24 characters? And btw. what have you tried?

Comment: @Thomas the strings are hex codes like `\x02\x00\x01\x04\x20\x27`, that are used to control a device through an rs232 serial port. I haven't really been able to find anything to try to convert the string to what I actually need `[0x02,0x00,0x01,0x04,0x20,0x27]` so I can send it to the device via JavaScript.

Comment: `var array = [...string].map(char => char.charCodeAt(0))`